# Usage of "wanna", "hafta"

Tags: infinitives, slang, colloquial-language

In *"THE MORPHOLEXICAL NATURE OF ENGLISH to-CONTRACTION"*, Pullum quotes four examples of usage of *"wants to"/"wansta"*:

> (5)
>   a. Teddy is the man Mike **wants to** send.
>   b. Teddy is the man Mike **wants to** go.
>   c. Teddy is the man Mike **wansta** send.
>   d. *Teddy is the man Mike **wansta** go.

I would like to understand the difference between 5c and 5d, and what makes 5d ungrammatical.

---

* is used to mark a sentence as ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the difference between 5c and 5d, let's consider the following transformations:

> (I)
> a. Mike **wansta** send Teddy.
> b. Mike **wants** Teddy to go.
>
> (II)
> a. Teddy is the man; Mike **wansta** send him.
> b. Teddy is the man; Mike **wants** him to go.
>
> (III)
> a. Teddy is the man Mike **wansta** send.
> b. Teddy is the man Mike **wants** to go.

These transformations suggest that the *to*-contraction is only grammatical for a string of words of the form "WANT + to + [infinitive]".

Let's try to test how far this rule goes by using a *negative infinitive*:

> (IV)
> a. I'll do any damned thing I **have to** not to drink.
> b. I'll do any damned thing I **hafta** not to drink.

In conclusion, 5d is ungrammatical because it doesn't follow the pattern
"WANT + to + [infinitive]".

Comment: Is the "wansta" contraction used in written  English, because I've never seen it?

Comment: @jinawee, no, it is not, it is used specifically by pullum to illustrate this linguistic point (which is very interesting). the point is that the non-pronunciation of the final t is prohibited in certain contexts.

Comment: @jinawee, [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KgCGUSjq5UgC&lpg=PA120&dq=wansta&pg=PA121#v=onepage&q=wansta&f=false)'s an example. I reckon it is avoided in written English unless there's a reason to reproduce informal speech literally.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative explanation: in colloquial English, wanna, hafta, gonna, have been reanalyzed infinitive constructions to modal verbs exactly like "must," "would," "should," etc. So the following is ungrammatical

> *This is the candidate that I wanna win.

because the subject of "wanna" does not match the subject of "win."

(I switched to the first person because I want to separate the issue from wants to vs. "wansta.")

This explanation jives with the intuitive problem when you hear the (*) sentence ("wait, YOU wanna win??") and doesn't require transformational grammar, which, regardless of its truth value, is not so easy to learn for second language learners!